# Insert SVG element before another SVG element with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I am plotting a graph using D3.js library.

I need to insert a svg element before svg element with class "abc".

This is what i tried to do:

```
gParent[0][0].insertBefore("g", $('.abc'))
.attr({
            class: "axis-down",
            transform: "translate(120, 120)"
        })
```

But, it doesn't work and gives an error.

This works fine but it appends g after abc and not before

```
gParent.append("g")
    .attr({
                class: "axis-down",
                transform: "translate(120, 120)"
            })
```

gParent is the parent node.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D3, the syntax is simply .insert(svg:elementType, "CSS Selector")

So this will work:

```
gParent.insert("g", ".abc")
.attr({
            class: "axis-down",
            transform: "translate(120, 120)"
        })
```

Comment: Will that create a new svg element with class axis-down before .abc?

Comment: I tried and it worked. Thanks Elijah. You are awesome :)