# d3 how to insert new SVG element before existing other element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983256/insert-svg-element-before-another-svg-element-with-class) I think I learnt how to do this but I can't quite believe I've got it right as it's ugly as you like.

Let's say there's an element `#foo` and I want to create an `SVG` element *before* it. Do I really have to do this:

```
var svg = d3.select(d3.select('#foo').node().parentNode)
  .insert('svg', '#foo')
```

Am I missing something? (EDIT: to be clear, the sample code above does work, but it's pretty opaque and includes repetition of the selector.)

Answer (score 5):

You just need the `type` and the `selector`:

```
selection.insert(type, before)
```

For instance, in this demo, the circle is an element with ID `foo`. So,

```
var svg2 = svg.insert("svg", "#foo");
```

Inserts a child SVG before the circle element.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
var circle = svg.append("circle").attr("id", "foo");
var svg2 = svg.insert("svg", "#foo");
svg2.attr("id", "childSVG");

var mySVG = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg.node());
console.log(mySVG)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. However I'm not sure it answers my question - you are starting with the assumption of a selection which is the parent into which you want to insert something. My question is about the initial creation of an SVG element before a known other element in the DOM.